# Checking a string in a list if there is a word in that string

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

So say I have

```
list = ['I am blue', 'I am red', 'I am not blue', 'I am green']
```

Is there a way to create a new  list such that it will contain only the entries in "list" that contain the word 'blue' (and disregard the other parts of that string)? i.e.

```
blue_list = ['I am blue', 'I am not blue']
```

and then I'd need to check the amt of entries in "blue_list" but I can do that with

```
len(blue_list)
```

Thanks!

Comment: String containment and word containment are very different problems.  "blue" is a part of the word "abluent", for example: do you want "the abluent was effective" to be removed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension, while you're at it rename your list so that it doesn't shadow the built in:

```
l = ['I am blue', 'I am red', 'I am not blue', 'I am green']
blue_list = [phrase for phrase in l if 'blue' in phrase]
```